# Swift - captureOutput frame extracted color is always coming near to black

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, ios-camera

I am trying to process the video frames and extracting the concentrated color out of it. I was using the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` but it was making the shutter sound everytime I take a frame for the processing so I switched to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and now processing each frame as it comes by.

Here is the code I am using:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        currentFrame = self.convertImageFromCMSampleBufferRef(sampleBuffer);
        if let image = UIImage(CIImage: currentFrame){
            if let color = self.extractColor(image) {                    
                // print the color code
            }
        }
    }

    func convertImageFromCMSampleBufferRef(sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> CIImage{
        let pixelBuffer:CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        return ciImage;
    }
```

With the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` I was getting almost correct output but with the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` the values are always near to black even if the camera view is into the bright light. I am guessing the problem is around the framerate or something but not able to figure it out.

In the last few test run this is the only color code I am getting `#1b1f01`

I would love to use the original `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` code but it should not make the Shutter sound and I am not able to disable it.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Had this same issue myself. It was just that it was very early; for whatever reason the camera sensor starts at 0 and is willing to give you frames before what you'd think of as the first frame is fully exposed.

Solution: just wait a second before you expect any real images.